# Why is the value of SP register 07h when 8051 is powered up?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, 8051

When the 8051 is powered up, the **Stack pointer** register contains value `07h` not `00h`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of `Bank 0` is the default register bank used by `8051`. This `bank 0` uses registers `0 - 7`.

If the `SP` starts from `0` registers `R0 - 7` would overwrite the `SP` and cause undefined behavior, at least.

Usually the `SP` is set to the desired location with startup code